# Adding enum values for writing to the event log

Tags: .net, event-log

When writing to the event log, our application uses enums to generate an error number to attach to event log items. The idea is to list the things that we know can go wrong, and assign IDs to each one so we can identify right away what went wrong when viewing the event log.

One enum contains values/IDs that represent a class in the application, and another enum contains values representing error codes for known errors that may occur during execution (e.g. invalid date=1, invalid amount=2 and so on).

Now, say we've detected an invalid input to a method. We add up the appropriate class ID that contains the method from one enum, and the specific "invalid input" error from the second enum, and then we pass the result of the addition to the EventLog.WriteEntry () method along with the message string.

The problem is that when we pass a variable containing the result of the enum values' addition to the WriteEntry() method, nothing gets written to the event log. However, if the value is passed as a regular integer in the method's parameters, then the event is written successfully.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What happens when you debug? So they values always show correctly?  Also can you post a code snippet showing what you are doing?

Comment: Are you using VB.NET? If so, then please turn Option Strict On, and never turn it off again. This sounds like there is either a compile-time error or a runtime exception that you are ignoring.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately turning option strict on causes a whole bunch of other issues (implicit conversion warnings, etc) and the cost of fixing those problems is simply overwhelming. I always use option strict, but my predecessors didn't like it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Put two calls to your event log into your code, e.g. something like:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(1005);
EventLog.WriteEntry(MethodIDs.FirstMethod + ErrorIDs.FifthError);
```

Put a breakpoint on the first line, run the program, and then single-step through both calls to the function, watching what happens.

You will probably find the problem within a few seconds.

Comment: The 1st call would write to the event log just fine, but the 2nd one would do nothing.

Comment: Did you single step it?
If you can't single step it, then put some calls in to write out what is happening as your code is running. e.g. If you're using VB, then somehting like: MessageBox.Show("WriteEntry called with value" & value). Put these calls throughout the WriteEntry function so it will report its progress as it works its way through the code. You are probably passing a silly value (like -6 instead of 1005) into the function, and then a If statement is causing nothing to happen. If you want more help, please post your WriteEntry code and an example of a call to it.

Answer (score 0):

why would you use enums for those in any case?

Wouldn't it make much more sense to use extensions to Exceptions?

e.g. `throw new InvalidArgumentException("error message")`